# Database Query setup

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

The DB columns are |name|userID|lastname|UserPass|age|gender| i am building a query to select multiple results in one request

```
   global $wpdb;

   $res = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT name, lastname
         FROM datatable
         WHERE userID in ( %d , %d)
         AND
         UserPass in ( %d, %d  )",
         array(
            $val[1],
            $val[2],
            $val[3],
            $val[4],
         )

        ),
        ARRAY_A
    );
```

where $val[1] and $val[2] should be uset as userID, and $val[3] and $val[4] UserPass. And i think i have problem with ordering the placeholder values and that the query is not setup properly, could use a word of advice.

Comment: its a simple PDO statement or word-press prepare statement ?

Comment: its simple, i was using the prepare only because of the placeholders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this :

```
 $querystr = "
    SELECT name, lastname
         FROM datatable
         WHERE userID in ('your user ids implode with commas')
         AND
         UserPass in ('password string implode with commas ')
 ";

 $result = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

Answer (score 0):

This query returns all the users that match the given passwords.

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;

   $res = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT name, lastname, UserPass
         FROM datatable
         WHERE userID in ( %d , %d)
         HAVING UserPass in ( %d, %d  )",
         array(
            $val[1],
            $val[2],
            $val[3],
            $val[4],
         )

        ),
        ARRAY_A
    );
?>
```

Maybe this helps?

Comment: I need only there name and last name, and what i wanted to know rly was if the structure is good and if the placeholder values are writen good, so if 
WHERE userID in (  $val[1] , $val[2])
AND
 UserPass in ( $val[3], $val[4]  )" has that order of reading